# React Native Project Setup issue

Tags: react-native, command-line-interface

I am trying to setup a react native project in Ubuntu and encoutering this issue..

```
/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-doctor/build/commands/doctor.js:127 description: description ?? healthcheck.description SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?

at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dell/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-doctor/build/index.js:13:38)
```

react-native Project Setup